# Get whole decimal digits for precision after Splitting List of float numbers in Pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, precision

i hav df with lat long as list

df:

| coord |
| --- |
| [-76.02140426635742, 32.88458068648376, 0.0] |
| [-76.02140426635742, 32.88458068648376, 0.0] |

i used str.get(0)

```
df['lat']=df['coord'].str.get(0)
```

what i got is

| coord | lat |
| --- | --- |
| [-76.02140426635742, 32.88458068648376, 0.0] | -76.021404 |
| [-76.02140426635742, 32.88458068648376, 0.0] | -76.021404 |

but i want the whole digits to be taken for precision.

expected output dataframe:

| coord | lat | lon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [-76.02140426635742, 32.88458068648376, 0.0] | -76.02140426635742 | 32.88458068648376 |
| [-76.02140426635742, 32.88458068648376, 0.0] | -76.02140426635742 | 32.88458068648376 |

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.set_option("precision", 14)
```

Pandas default to display 6 decimal places.  You can change it to e.g. 14 decimal places as above.